"The search request was unable to connect to the Search Service." - SharePoint Online
I'm having this message since this morning on two out of three tenants my company has.
Basically, I can trigger it when I try to go for instance in the search schema, there I will be greeted with this message, alongside with a correlation Id.
My question is do any of you have this issue right now ?
I'm considering logging a case with Microsoft to be honest.
Thank you

There was a Search Service outage in Microsoft 365. For us it's already passing.
You should see Service Degradation in your Admin Center. There should be also a post-incident report.
As an admin, you cannot really do much. Open a service request only if you need some official statement for compliance/reporting reasons.

Indeed, it was restored in the evening. But we didn't see aything related in the admin center, that's weird. Oh well. Cloud services fun isn't it. Thank you for your input mate :)

As weird as it sounds, you can also watch Twitter/X for updates on current issues....

It was Microsoft doing its stuff in behind. It was fun to handle all of the angry users while it lasts.
